# mysql c# connection problems (system.net.sockets.socketexception)

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an application in C# that uses a mySQL database. When I run the code in debug mode, I am seeing a lot of exceptions thrown when it tries to connect (system.net.sockets.socketexception errors). Here is some sample code:

```
        MySqlConnection gSQLConnection;
        MySqlCommand sqlCommand;
        MySqlDataReader sqlReader;

        summaryPortfolioStats stats = new summaryPortfolioStats();

        gSQLConnection = new MySqlConnection(sdbConn);
        sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("LH_GetPortfolioStatsFromIndexAssets", gSQLConnection);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        MySqlParameter sqlParameter = sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("InIdx_i", MySqlDbType.Int32));
        sqlParameter.Value = iIndex;
        sqlParameter = sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("InStart_i", MySqlDbType.Int32));
        sqlParameter.Value = iStartAsset;
        sqlParameter = sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("InEnd_i", MySqlDbType.Int32));
        sqlParameter.Value = iEndAsset;

        gSQLConnection.Open();
        sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

The Open command seems to trigger an exception in system.dll and the ExecuteReader command seems to trigger an exception in MySQL.Data.dll.

Here is a sample of the error messages that I see (from VS output window):

[image: Messages from VS output window]

The application does eventually connect with the database and get the data, but this is significantly slowing down the application.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: When you arent debugging - how long does it take to open the connection?

Comment: There's no noticeable difference when I run the compiled software. I have a version sitting on Azure that uses SQL Server and it's way faster.

Comment: Some things do throw silent exceptions which are out of our control, under debug it can cause slower effects, and concern, but, its out of our hands.. so how fast is it on run conditions not debug conditions?

Comment: I think their are `first change` exception. You don't have to deal with them. Their are catch in mySql driver code.

Comment: When I run the model in Debug mode, it takes 5.3 mins. In release mode it takes 5.2 mins. I guess the main point is that I shouldn't worry about it?